# Which C standard should I stick to?

Tags: c, standards

Out of C18, C11, C99, and ANSI C, which standard should I (currently) stick to, and why? What is the best way to find out which compilers support which standards? How does this choice differ for different programming domains?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Out of C18, C11, C99, and ANSI C, which standard should I (currently) stick to, and why?

In general the latest. Use the latest unless you have some argument against.

One argument against using C18 is that the documentation does not seem to be freely available yet, but C11 is. Well, freely and freely. At least they are here: [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/) Note that these are not the *final* ones, but for most purposes they are good enough. Thanks to @Lundin and @JohnBode for pointing it out.

Another argument is that there may be platforms you want to support where a newer standard is not supported.

And I would strongly advice against ANSI unless you have no other choice. The C99 version was a very big improvement. After that, there are some nice new features, but the biggest change was C99.

> What is the best way to find out which compilers support which standards?

Google. Or look in the documentation for the compilers you are interested in. However, be aware that some compilers may not be 100% compliant with a certain C version, even if they claim to be.

Comment: None of these are freely available; ISO is commercial and ISO 9899 is not an open standard. However, some drafts are _very_ close to the official standard. In C11 I think pretty much the only difference was some typo regarding `__STDC_VERSION__` in the draft.

Comment: The "freely available" versions ([N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for C2011 and [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) for C99) are not the final, "official" versions, and they may contain some errors.  For most purposes though, they should be good enough.

Comment: I know this may sound like a dummy question but does a greater number mean a later version?

Comment: @havryliuk Nah, sorta. C89 is from 1989, C99 is from 1999, C11 is from 2011 and so on

Comment: @klutt oh, thanks a lot! It wasn't a stupid question after all XD

Answer (score 4):

Usually, the latest standard, as soon as it's released, supersedes all other existing standards. So, theoretically, it's the latest one available at any time.

However, not all compilers will be up-to-date to support the latest standard revision - the practical answer is: whichever is the latest version supported by your environment, is usually best to use.

Comment: The problem is that "your environment" will often not be where the code has to build. There are extremely complex issues of compatibility here.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, this is often a matter of organizational policy rather than personal preference. And the reasons for the organizational policy are often not technical - they're tied up with support contracts and staff training and matters like that.

If you have the good fortune to be able to make the choice entirely yourself, you still need to consider matters such as the range of platforms you want to support, and the currentness of the compilers that will be available to people who might have to build your code, other than yourself.

If you have a complete free hand in this area, consider yourself lucky ;)

Answer (score 0):

You most likely are asking for a decision which you have to make yourself and which will only affect you. Let me nevertheless put it into a wider context. If you are a professional then in whatever project you are contributing to, there is (or should be) one person responsible for that decision. I consider it obvious that for a larger project it is most important that everybody uses the same compiler version and standard; to avoid unpredictable differences.
This does of course not mean that intentional testing and comparing of behaviour should be skipped; but I assume that in a project which has somebody for making the compiler/version/standard decision there also is an planned activity for that.
So, if there is a person for the decision defined: Do what that person decides. Maybe offer to review their decision or to participate in the testing and comparing.

In case you are free to decide (because you are that person or because the whole project is just you), then at first go with the latest revision (like other answers recommend), assuming you do not happen to have good reasons to the contrary.
Then, when another one becomes available, redecide consciously; I recommend to tend to stay with the one you started with, if there are no relevant benefits to be had from newer one.
That is because in case of a (professional multi-person) project with a non-negligible code base, deciding to use a newer compiler (implied by a newer standard being supported) is risky. It would at least make a regression test necessary.

Comment: @JohnAllen I do not see how that invalidates what I wrote, which mostly (by length of text and by detail of discussion) is about the decision as made by a single person, be it for themselves or for a project.  I recommend something and discuss future decisions. The part which you dismiss, the first paragraph, assuming that you did not only read the second sentence of that paragraph, is introduced by an "if" defining the scope. That scope, even for a question author only asking about a decision for them alone, is, among otherthings, illustrating the need to decide with awareness of the context.

Comment: True. I will remove my downvote. I would probably remove the first paragraph as it is not helpful

Comment: @JohnAllen Thanks for your input. After a few hours in which it kept reoccuring to me, I decided to review and rephrase both paragraphs, to make the initial widening of context and the only later application to personal situation more obviously intentional. I am quite satisfied now and think that it better avoids the impression you got. But you are very much right to stay with your opinion and keep your vote, if you still are unsatisfied with my approach. Have fun, thanks for being a reflecting and communicating voter here.